# Query using relation in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have made a query in Hyperledger Composer where in the query tries to search for all invoices of a borrower. The borrower is a participant of the invoice asset:

```
asset Invoice identified by invoiceId {
  o String invoiceId
  o String invoiceRef optional
  o DateTime dateCreated
  o String type
  o DateTime invoiceOrPurchaseDate optional
  o Double amount
  o DateTime invoiceDueDate optional
  o String paymentStatus optional
  o Boolean overdue
  o Double outstandingBalance
  --> Participant borrower
  --> Participant lender
}
```

I need a query that will return all invoices of a borrower and I did this in Hyperledger composer by coding below:

```
query QInvoiceByBorrower {
    description: "Select invoice by borrower"
    statement:
        SELECT org.n.blockchaindemo.Invoice
            WHERE (_$borrower == borrower)
}
```

But when I try to call the query through REST API, I get [] empty result as below:

```
http://10.10.4.244:3000/api/queries/QInvoiceByBorrower?borrower=resource:org.n.blockchaindemo.User#1381991
```

May I know how to create a query that will search using a foreign relation in Hyperledger Composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you Invoice definition you need to refer to your specific Participant type i.e. **User** rather that the system type Participant.  So the last part of your Invoice will be:

```
  o Double outstandingBalance
  --> User borrower
  --> User lender
 }
```

With this change your Query should work.  A useful diagnostic method is to create a duplicate query without the *where* clause and then examine the returned data to help understand the parameters to use for a query.

(By using Participant I think your asset will include the first participant type in your model at the time the asset type was first used - this sounds like it could generate some unexpected behaviours, so specifying the actual participant type makes sense.)